# Php.Проблемы с кодировкой при загрузке файла VK api curl

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, curl, fileupload

Есть php скрипт - для загрузки видео в вк по апи.Метод video.save.Если файл видео в папке с русскими символами в заглавие то не грузит.Если цифры или английские то грузит - все хорошо.

```
     $ch = curl_init();
$parameters = http_build_query([
    'access_token' => $token, // access_token / ключ доступа
    'v'            => VK_API_VERSION, // версия API
    'name'         => $title,
    'description'  => '',
    'group_id'     => $groupid, // ID группы
    'no_comments'  => 0 // разрешаем комментирование
]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.vk.com/method/video.save?' . $parameters);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);


$curl_result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE); // превращаем JSON-массив, который нам вернул VK, в обычный PHP-массив

curl_close($ch);

// // //
// Загружаем видео на серверы ВК
// // //

$ch = curl_init();

$parameters = [
    'video_file' => new CURLFile(__DIR__ . "/uploads/".$file)  // PHP >= 5.5.0
    
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_result['response']['upload_url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, TRUE); // если PHP < 5.5.0, то эту строку надо закомментировать
$curl_result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE);
curl_close($ch);
```

А если вручную в вк видео добавлять то русскоязычные названия можно.Ставил кодировку в скрипте mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); не помогает.Визуально ошибок не выдает
пишет - что видео загружено, var_dump на странице выдает нормально читаемые русские символы названия видео.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос перекодировать надо .У вк другая кодировка
$file2= iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $file);